# How to create a setter for a class without the name of class attribute in Python 3.x?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Usually, we set a value for the class attribute using the attribute name:

```
class Value:
        def __init__(self, value=None):
            self.value = value
        #setter definition  block
    >>>my_obj = Value()
    >>>my_obj.value = 10
```

But I want to do it without the name of attribute. 
It should work like code below:

```
class Value:
    def __init__(self, value=None):
        self.value = value
    #setter definition  block
>>>my_obj = Value()
>>>my_obj = 10
>>>print(myObj.value)
10
```

It means that it don't use name for the attribute named "value". If you set any value (10) for the class `Value()` then this value will be set for the attribute named `Value.value`.

Is it possible?

Comment: That is not possible, and it would be very strange if you hacked the interpreter/runtime to get it to work that way. Just use `myObj.value = 10`

Comment: Even if possible, honestly, there is *no gain at all* in doing `my_obj = 10` rather than `my_obj.value = 10`. You would only add ambiguity to your code, making whoever reads it in the future have really a hard time

Answer (score -1):

Here is something I messed around with while trying to answer your question. I was not sure why you would want to set something in your class without knowing what it is (seems a bit like nonsense to me) so maybe you just want to set EVERYTHING in your class equal to 10.  The following should do that:

```
class Value:
    def __init__(self, value=None):
        self.value = value


abc = Value()
print(abc.value) # prints None

for i in dir(abc):
    if(i[0] != '_'):
        exec("abc."+i+"=10")


print(abc.value) # prints 10
```

By using `dir()` on your class you get all the methods and variables in that class.  All the pre-defined methods and variables start with two underscores if you are using a simple class definition, so by removing those we can access the values you added yourself to the class and assign to them with `exec()`.  I do not recommend doing this